# OpenGL vertex shader nonlinear transformation

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader

When I want to do a linear transformation, I can pass a transform matrix to the vertex shader to do matrix product.

```
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex
```

But what if I want to do a nonlinear transformation? For example, I want to rotate a cube around x axis by a angle theta = 0.1 * x, so the cube can be twisted in the end.

Comment: You can calculate whatever you want in the vertex shader. Note, that what you showed is a very outdated shader version.

Comment: Should I get the vertex's position in my main program and calculate a new transformation matrix or should I calculation the vertex's new position directly in the vertex shader?

Comment: That entirely depends on what exactly you want to do. But if you want something like `output = f(x,y,z) * vec3(x,y,z)`, then you can't find a matrix for doing that.

Comment: Note that when you do nonlinear transforms in the VS, it will only be applied to the end points of your primitives. You can bend your sapce in weird ways, but the edges still stay flat.

Comment: With the method of matrix products, I can stack several operations in a specific order, like ScaleMatrix * RotationMatrix * vertex_vec. Is there any way to add a nonlinear operation f(x, y, z) to my set of operations?

Comment: Again: It depends what you want to do: If it just a non-linear scaling factor, then sure why not. You should really describe in your question what exactly you want to do. Otherwise we are just guessing around and wasting everyones time.

Comment: Sorry about unclear statement. I just edited the example I want to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be implemented in a vertex shader. It doesn't really matter if you create a rotation matrix first, but for simplicity I will show how to apply the rotation directly:

```
float theta = 0.1 * gl_Vertex.x;

vec4 twisted_vertex = vec4(
         gl_Vertex.x,
         cos(theta) * gl_Vertex.y - sin(theta) * gl_Vertex.z,
         sin(theta) * gl_Vertex.y + cos(theta) * gl_Vertex.z,
         gl_Vertex.w);
```

You can now perform the usual calculation you already have on the twisted vertex instead of the original one, for example:

```
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewMatrix * twisted_vertex;
```

Note, that when you apply that to a simple cube (8 corner, 36 triangles), then the result might not be what you expect. The transformation is only applied to the vertices (the 8 corners) and not to the edges. If you want to twist a cube, then you have to make sure that it is tessellated high enough along the x-axis.

Edit: Here it goes for move along y, twist along x, move along z, twist along x. Basically, you can chain all these transformations as you want.

```
vec4 twist(vec4 v, float theta)
{
     vec4 twisted_vertex = vec4(
         v.x,
         cos(theta) * v.y - sin(theta) * v.z,
         sin(theta) * v.y + cos(theta) * v.z,
         v.w);
     return twisted_vertex;
}

//In main
//Move along y and first twist
vec4 v1 = twist(gl_Vertex + vec4(0, y_move, 0, 0));
//Move along z and second twist
vec4 v2 = twist(v1 + vec4(0, 0, z_move, 0));
```

You could also create the four transformation matrices and chain them, but this will most probably be slower and cost more operations.

Comment: How to do twisting after other operations? Like in this order: move along y, twist around x, move along z, twist around x.

Comment: Thats why I told you "explain **exactly** what you want to do".

Comment: Really sorry. I'm kind of coming out of this question before I'm clear of what I want to do.